# php отображение поля при условии

Tags: php

Есть php форма, на которой 2 `select`
При выборе первого наполняется второй

Стоит задача при выборе определенных значений из второго отображать 1-6 полей для ввода. Не понимаю как такое реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста

Понимаю, что у пути есть несколько примерных решений:

1. В БД прописано количество полей, но тут проблема в том что условие поимки количества полей можно получить только после выбора второго `select`
2. Использовать куки или что-то подобное, не работал с ними. То есть после выбора отправлять запрос и перезагружать форму при этом подставляя предыдущие значения

PHP 8.1, PostgreSQL

Comment: Технология ajax уже изобретена.

Comment: @u_mulder, спасибо, посмотрю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете через запрос получить данные для select и заполнит

```
  $.getJSON("updateTypes.php?q="+brandName, function(data) {
$("#Type").html('');
$.each(data, function(){
    $("#Type").append('<option value="'+ this.value +'">'+ this.name +'</option>')
)
})
```

Comment: Спасибо. Как раз о так варианте подумал. Проще `selest` ещё один создать и заполнять, нежели для каждого поле ввода создавать